# How to Understand Imam Mahdi's Arrival?

Tags: quran, hadith, imam-mahdi, last-day

Imam Mahdi's arrival  is one of the Biggest Sign of World Ending,Currently Most of the smallest signs of world ending are Happened(Including People with low Education will get in to the Power(ruling)) .On now days most of the People have a rejection Mentality to everything Because of Terrorist groups like ISIS.In such a situation how the People can understand the arrival of Mahdi Imam.Is there any natural signs provided by Quran or Hadith?

Comment: Imam Mehdi's emergence is NOT listed among the 10 major signs. Rather it is considered to be the bridge between the minor signs and the major signs. The Quran doesn't shed light on this subject. But there are many Hadiths on the matter. Would you like the answers from a sunni or shia perspective because they differ significantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the name of God, Most Beneficent, Most Merciful**

**All praise belongs to God. He does what he wishes. No one can object Him. He does not require anybody’s suggestion. He is not bound by anyone. He is not afraid of anyone. Indeed, all praises belongs to God who dominates all and no one can ever dominate Him.**

---

**Answer:**

There are several signs that would exactly tell us the when Imam Mahdi would emerge that includes total domination of Israel in the world, Sea of Galilee getting dry and the most siginifcant sign is the total destruction of Army that will come to attack from Syria.

The Holy Prophet Muhammad (SAW) has prophesied about several events that will occur just before the advent of the day of judgment. Among these, Rasulullah(SAW) has foretold the advent of one of his descendants, Al Mahdi (the guided one), which will materialize when the believers are severely oppressed in every corner of the world. He will fight the oppressors, unite the Muslims, bring peace and justice to the world, rule over the Arabs, and lead a prayer in Mekkah at which Jesus (pbuh) will be present.

Here’s a Sunnah:

> In hadith, it is narrated from Ibn Abbas(R.A.) that," Mahdi (A.S.) will appear at the time when people being upset would say that what for Mahdi (A.S.) would come now !! "

So practically, this is one of signs of the End of the World

Comment: From what I understand, Quran verse 31:34 tells only Allah knows the time of the Judgment Day. Verse 7:187 tells that Prophet Muhammed did not know the time of the Judgment Day, and that it will happen abruptly, unexpectedly (43:66). So, the thought that it is narrated from the Prophet that several events will occur "just before the advent of the day of judgment" in my opinion contradicts with the verses I mentioned. The Judgment Day will come all of a sudden; if it would come only after certain events, signs etc., so that people can prepare, it wouldn't be the Judgment Day in my opinion.